# Own alert is executed twice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small class with which I can make and display an alert. The duration of the alert and the content is given to the class via a class function and controlled.

When I trigger the toast it is shown and hidden again correctly after the durationTime. But then the alert appears again and is hidden again shortly afterwards. In no part of the code do I call the alert twice.

**Question:**
I suppose this could be related to the context and the timeset. But I have little experience with this. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance! Max

```js
class ToastHawaii {
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.duration = typeof(config.duration) == 'undefined' ? 1000 : config.duration;
    this.toastContainer = config.toastContainer;
  }

    makeToast(d) {
        const html = `<div class="toast">
          <div>${d.title}</div>
          <div class="right">${d.content}</div>
        </div>`;
        this.toastContainer.innerHTML = html;
        this.toastContainer.classList.add("show");
        setTimeout(() => { 
          this.toastContainer.classList.remove("show");
        }, this.duration);
    }
}

const mA = new ToastHawaii({
  duration: 4000,
  toastContainer: document.querySelector('#myAlertContainer')
});

const content = `ICON`;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  mA.makeToast({
    title: "hello", 
    content: content 
  });  
})
```

```css
#myAlertContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0%;
  top: 30px;  
  visibility: hidden;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  height:60px;
}
.toast {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

#myAlertContainer.show {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="myAlertContainer"></div>
<button>makeAlert!</button>
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTMHell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73836621/157247) explains what's wrong and shows one way to fix it, but the problem with that solution is that your JavaScript code is no longer in charge of how long the alert is showing.

Another approach is to use `transition` rather than `animation`; the transition back to the invisible state won't start until the class is removed (see marker comments in the CSS):

```js
class ToastHawaii {
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.duration = typeof(config.duration) == 'undefined' ? 1000 : config.duration;
    this.toastContainer = config.toastContainer;
  }

    makeToast(d) {
        const html = `<div class="toast">
          <div>${d.title}</div>
          <div class="right">${d.content}</div>
        </div>`;
        this.toastContainer.innerHTML = html;
        this.toastContainer.classList.add("show");
        setTimeout(() => { 
          this.toastContainer.classList.remove("show");
        }, this.duration);
    }
}

const mA = new ToastHawaii({
  duration: 4000,
  toastContainer: document.querySelector('#myAlertContainer')
});

const content = `ICON`;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  mA.makeToast({
    title: "hello", 
    content: content 
  });  
})
```

```css
#myAlertContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;                        /* <=== */
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  z-index: -1;                       /* <=== */
  transition: top 0.5s, opacity 0.5s /* <=== */
}
#myAlertContainer.show {
  z-index: 1;                        /* <=== */
  top: 30px;                         /* <=== */
  opacity: 1;                        /* <=== */
}
.toast {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myAlertContainer"></div>
<button>makeAlert!</button>
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

That way, it doesn't matter how long your code leaves the element up for, it will always takes half a second to appear, then half a second to disappear. (You could subtract that time from the delay before removing the class if you want to count it as part of the time "duration" controls.)

If you want the disappearance to take a different amount of time from the appearance, you can put a different `transition` in the `#myAlertContainer.show` rule. That will control the appearance, the the one in the `#myAlertContainer` rule will control disappearance. Here's a really slow disappearance:

```js
class ToastHawaii {
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.duration = typeof(config.duration) == 'undefined' ? 1000 : config.duration;
    this.toastContainer = config.toastContainer;
  }

    makeToast(d) {
        const html = `<div class="toast">
          <div>${d.title}</div>
          <div class="right">${d.content}</div>
        </div>`;
        this.toastContainer.innerHTML = html;
        this.toastContainer.classList.add("show");
        setTimeout(() => { 
          this.toastContainer.classList.remove("show");
        }, this.duration);
    }
}

const mA = new ToastHawaii({
  duration: 4000,
  toastContainer: document.querySelector('#myAlertContainer')
});

const content = `ICON`;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  mA.makeToast({
    title: "hello", 
    content: content 
  });  
})
```

```css
#myAlertContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;                        /* <=== */
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  z-index: -1;                       /* <=== */
  transition: top 2.5s, opacity 2.5s /* <=== */
}
#myAlertContainer.show {
  z-index: 1;                        /* <=== */
  top: 30px;                         /* <=== */
  opacity: 1;                        /* <=== */
}
.toast {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myAlertContainer"></div>
<button>makeAlert!</button>
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: I have one more question. Which of the two solutions do you find better / cleaner? I am leaning towards variant 1.

Comment: @MaxPattern - You mean the two in this answer, the first with equal timings or the second with a longer timing on disappearing? It's totally up to you, but I prefer equal, fairly quick transitions. I just wanted to show that you *could* make them different if you wanted to. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It happens because your timeout is for 4s, but the fade-out animation is 3s. Adjusting your timeout according to your CSS animation duration will fix it.

```js
class ToastHawaii {
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.duration = typeof(config.duration) == 'undefined' ? 1000 : config.duration;
    this.toastContainer = config.toastContainer;
  }

    makeToast(d) {
        const html = `<div class="toast">
          <div>${d.title}</div>
          <div class="right">${d.content}</div>
        </div>`;
        this.toastContainer.innerHTML = html;
        this.toastContainer.classList.add("show");
        setTimeout(() => { 
          this.toastContainer.classList.remove("show");
        }, this.duration);
    }
}

const mA = new ToastHawaii({
  duration: 3000,
  toastContainer: document.querySelector('#myAlertContainer')
});

const content = `ICON`;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  mA.makeToast({
    title: "hello", 
    content: content 
  });  
})
```

```css
#myAlertContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0%;
  top: 30px;  
  visibility: hidden;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  height:60px;
}
.toast {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

#myAlertContainer.show {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="myAlertContainer"></div>
<button>makeAlert!</button>
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: The eight sense and that's what it's all about! Thanks a lot!!! Do you have an idea how to control the css fadeout synchronously with the js timeduration property? Probably only with js css varaible modification. Or is my solution rather not so good? Which way would be better here?

Comment: Instead of adding a setTimeout, add a transitionend event listener. This event listener will run when the animation ends, no matter how long the animation is. You can read more about it hereÖ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event

Comment: @MaxPattern I've updated my answer. Adding `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` will fix the flickering altogether. About controlling the duration, you don't need to have too much control over it, so hard coding a few variables should work well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your animation duration. Your fadeout animation duration is 2.5s and you remove show class from your settimeout after 4000 milisecond. That's why they are conflicting. I changed you animation duration and it is solved.

```js
class ToastHawaii {
  constructor(config = {}) {
    this.duration = typeof(config.duration) == 'undefined' ? 1000 : config.duration;
    this.toastContainer = config.toastContainer;
  }

    makeToast(d) {
        const html = `<div class="toast">
          <div>${d.title}</div>
          <div class="right">${d.content}</div>
        </div>`;
        this.toastContainer.innerHTML = html;
        this.toastContainer.classList.add("show");
        setTimeout(() => { 
          this.toastContainer.classList.remove("show");
        }, this.duration);
    }
}

const mA = new ToastHawaii({
  duration: 4000,
  toastContainer: document.querySelector('#myAlertContainer')
});

const content = `ICON`;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  mA.makeToast({
    title: "hello", 
    content: content 
  });  
})
```

```css
#myAlertContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0%;
  top: 30px;  
  visibility: hidden;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  height:60px;
}
.toast {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  height:100%;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: center;
}

#myAlertContainer.show {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 3.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;} 
  to {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
  to {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {top: 30px; opacity: 1;}
  to {top: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="myAlertContainer"></div>
<button>makeAlert!</button>
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: Hello Asif! Thank you for your answer! You are right! Colleague @HTMHell had already given the answer a few minutes ago. Therefore, the answer is redudant. But maybe you have an idea in response to this comment?